# Oracle SQL Query to change column headers on basis of conditions from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

**EDIT: This post is related to Oracle and requirement is for sql expression to fulfill requirement below.**

I have a requirement where there is table called data with columns:

```
DATA_ID
APP_ID
COLUMN_1
COLUMN_2
COLUMN_3
```

I have to write a query which replaces the Column header names with the ones in the table DATA_HEADER on the basis of app_id.

So if app_id=1, the columns would be :

```
COLUMN_1 :> Name
COLUMN_2 :> Status
COLUMN_3 :> Assigned
```

And if app_id=2, the columns would be :

```
COLUMN_1 :> Title 
COLUMN_2 :> Status
COLUMN_3 :> Title_New
```

There should be additional condition, if there is no name in data_header it would stick with the original column name, i.e. COLUMN_1,COLUMN_2,COLUMN_3 as in future according to app_ids there will be more/less column headers available as per app_id. SO if column header is present, it should replace, else remain original.

The 2 tables would be joined on basis of APP_ID.

Comment: The solution to this depends on where you want to run this query. In apex, the headers of a report are a region attribute. I don't know how to get the column headers in sqlplus dynamically. It would help if you explain the business requirement...

Comment: In apex, how would i add these to column headers? In apex, i create an IG select col01...col03 from data; Then Say for col01,created page item P1_COL1 and for the item write query like. select header_name from data_header where id=1 and app_id=:app_id. Now how will i assign this page item to the column in interactive grid? (The apex requirement needs to be done on IG)

Comment: I described it in the answer below ? As someone suggested in that other question, it would be very helpful if you created a sample app in a test workspace on apex.oracle.com so we could have a look at it.

Comment: Although for P4_APP_ID, in original app there are too many javascript  conditons which i couldn't replicate. If we can just work around it would be great

Comment: @KoenLostrie I hope you were able to login

Comment: @KoenLostrie There is one more thing that needs to be taken care of. if a column header is not found in data header column, it should stick to original column value. Ex:  For ay app_id 3, there's no value for COLUMN_1, it should simply show COLUMN_1

Comment: Updated my answer. Pls comment on the answer instead of on the question - this comment is a comment on my answer, not on your entire post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a sample app in your workspace, based on the sample data emp/dept (can be loaded via sql workshop > utilities > sample datasets). I added a table emp_header with some data. The idea is that you define a different column header for a database column per a different application

```
create table emp_header (
    id                             number generated by default on null as identity  
                                   constraint emp_header_id_pk primary key,
    app_id                         number,
    db_column_name                 varchar2(100) not null,
    report_header                  varchar2(100) not null
)
;

insert into emp_header (app_id, db_column_name, report_header ) values (1, 'ENAME', 'Employee Name');
insert into emp_header (app_id, db_column_name, report_header ) values (2, 'ENAME', 'Ename');
insert into emp_header (app_id, db_column_name, report_header ) values (1, 'JOB', 'Employee Job');
insert into emp_header (app_id, db_column_name, report_header ) values (2, 'JOB', 'Job');
```

On the home page I created a select list where a user can select an application. On select of the value, the page gets submitted an redirected to page 2.
In page 2 there are 2 page items: P2_COLUMN_1 and P2_COLUMN_2 with a computation before header to set the value when the page is loaded.
Example computation:

```
DECLARE
  l_returnvalue emp_header.report_header%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT report_header 
    INTO l_returnvalue
    FROM emp_header WHERE db_column_name = 'ENAME' AND app_id = :P2_APP_ID;
  RETURN l_returnvalue;
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  RETURN 'ENAME Original Value';
END;
```

As you can see in the computation code, there is a fallback value in case no value is found in the emp_header table. In this case it is 'ENAME Original Value', but you can make it whatever you want.

In the report attributes column attributes, the heading for column ENAME is set to &P2_COLUMN_1. and for column JOB to &P2_COLUMN_2.
Run page 1 and select a value for app id. See the different column headers based on your selection.

Comment: You changed the question tags (removed Oracle 12c and added Oracle Apex); how do you know it is about Apex? I mean, `app_id` could be *anything*, not related to Apex ...

Comment: @Littlefoot  I have similar query for apex too but in different thread. This question was on db level. However similar requirement is for apex too and i need help in that too inc ase you could take a look.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63609252/oracle-apex-change-dynamically-interactive-grid-column-names

Comment: @Littlefoot good point, this user had been posting apex questions for the last couple of days so I assumed this was for apex as well. Will remove the tag and update my answer

Comment: SELECT
  column_1,
  column_2
  INTO
    :P1_COLUMN_1_HEADER,
    :P1_COLUMN_2_HEADER
  FROM data_header
 WHERE app_id = :APP_ID; This query won't work because data_header doesn't have column_1....columns so it will throw error. Did you mean : SELECT
  column_1,
  column_2
  INTO
    :P1_COLUMN_1_HEADER,
    :P1_COLUMN_2_HEADER
  FROM data --this table
 WHERE app_id = :APP_ID;

Comment: Also, columns would be assigned like, IF  app_id=1,id=1 then column_1-> Name. If app_id=2,id=1, then column_1-> Title

Comment: For apex, i tried one thing though. For the column 1  item wrote: select header_name from data_header where id=1 and app_id=:APP_ID. Then in main IG query wrote, select column 1 as &P1_COLUMN_1_HEADER. But it is not changing names. it just placed column name as &P1_COLUMN_1_HEADER . In page process i wrote query like: select column_1 into :P1...HEADER from data where app_id=:APP_ID. This is not working

Comment: as someone suggested in that other question, it would be very helpful if you created a sample app in a test workspace on apex.oracle.com so we could have a look at it.

Comment: ok, can we ignore apex for a while and stick to this post. I am sorry for bringing the other thread leading to confusion between apex and oracle. maybe this can also help if you could suggest on drafting the query as per the original quetion..I have updated OP with expected output too as you had asked in your question..

Answer (score 1):

SQL statements that return a variable result set require Oracle Data Cartridge, ANYDATASET, and other tricks. Instead of coding that yourself, you can use my open source program [Method4](https://github.com/method5/method4). After installing it, you must write a query that generates the query, like this:

```
select * from table(method4.dynamic_query(
    q'[
        select
            'select data_id, app_id, ' ||
            'COLUMN_1 ' || max(case when id = 1 then '"'|| header_name || '"' else null end) || ', ' ||
            'COLUMN_2 ' || max(case when id = 2 then '"'|| header_name || '"' else null end) || ', ' ||
            'COLUMN_3 ' || max(case when id = 3 then '"'|| header_name || '"' else null end) ||
            ' from data where app_id = 2' sql_statement
        from data_header
        where app_id = 2
    ]'
));

DATA_ID   APP_ID   Title   Status     Title New
-------   ------   -----   --------   ---------
    100        2   Anna    Inactive   BA
    100        2   Ronnie  Active     MI and AI
```

Alternatively, if you're using 18c you could create a polymorphic table function. But as others have pointed out, this problem is usually best solved in an application like Apex.